# Are there any Bible verses about 'Being on your Knees' that do not specifically mention praying?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, verse-identification

I'm writing a dystopian novel and am looking for a Bible verse that I could potentially take out of context. Although it sounds bad, I can assure you in no way, shape, or form is this book anti-Christian.

That being said, I'm looking for a Bible verse, preferably short(er), one that mentions being on your knees but does not specifically mention praying.

Obviously, in the actual Bible there's more surrounding context in nearby verses but once that verse is removed from the context, I am then able to twist the words to something more suggestive.

In essence, I'm searching for something I could use as a double-entendre but although I've been searching for awhile now, have continued to come up empty handed.

I should clarify that I am unsure of whether or not a Bible verse mentioning one 'being on their knees' in a potentially suggestive manner exists.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site. Unfortunately we don't really do verse search questions here. But I hope you'll stick around and ask and answer many more questions. If you haven't, have a read of the site [tour].

Comment: For your future reference, there are tools that allow you to search for all occurrence of a particular word or phrase in the Bible. Printed versions are called Concordances, but most Bible websites have a search function. Here is an example of a search for [all the King James Version verses containing the word 'knees'.](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=knees&qs_version=KJV)

Answer (score 1):

As Mac’s Musings has already mentioned, in 2 Kings 1:13 a captain of the king “fell on his knees before Elijah” to beg for mercy.  Here are some more Old Testament verses that describe people getting down on their knees for reasons other than to pray:

> Kneeling before a king to seek favour: “Bathsheba bowed low and knelt before the king (David)” (1 Kings 1:16).
>
> Kneeling in worship of pagan gods: “I reserve seven thousand in Israel – all whose knees have not bowed down to Baal and all whose mouths have not kissed him” (1 Kings 19:18).
>
> Kneeling as an act of worship: “The whole assembly bowed in worship... the king and everyone present with him knelt down and worshipped” (2 Chronicles 29:28-29).
>
> Kneeling to pay honour to an official: “All the royal officials at the king’s gate knelt down and paid honour to Haman, for the king had commanded this concerning him.  But Mordecai would not kneel down or pay him honour” (Esther 3:2).
>
> Kneeling as an act of worship and submission:  “Come, let us bow down in worship, let us kneel before the Lord our Maker” (Psalm 95:6).

Comment: Although your answer is factual, shows research and is helpful in understanding biblical situations of being on one's knees, have you considered that you are being Devil's Advocate here? It is one of his trade-marks to wrest scripture out of context and suggest a base meaning! Or, maybe I should address my comments to the Asker? Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous verses that talk about fall on one's knees that do not discuss praying but these all involve begging a person in some way.

Here are a few: 2 Kings 1:13, 9:24; Matt 18:26, 29.

There are more texts that do not mention praying but people begging Jesus on their knees.  Some might argue that this is still praying before God.  Here are some of those.  Mark 10:17, 5:6, 1:40, 5:33, Matt 2:11, Luke 8:47.